# ActiveMQ(MQTT) crash when subscribe

Tags: php, activemq-classic, mqtt

I Download ActiveMQ Broker v5.11.1 And Run It
(Use MQTT).
I Can Publish And Subscribe With Websocket & PHP For Publish And Broker Work Well.

**But** When Use PHP for **subscribe** Broker Console Give Me This ERROR And Dont Subscribe Topic

```
      WARN : Transport Connection to :tcp://127.0.0.1:18967
     failed:java.io.IOExeption:Unexpected error 
     occurred:java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :12
```

This Error In A loop That Port Error(tcp://127.0.0.1:**18967**) In Each Period Is Changed

Subscribe.php

```
<?php

require("../phpMQTT.php");


$mqtt = new phpMQTT("localhost", 1883, "phpMQTT Sub Example"); //Change client name to something unique

if(!$mqtt->connect()){
    exit(1);
}

$topics['chat/general'] = array("qos"=>0, "function"=>"procmsg");
$mqtt->subscribe($topics,0);

while($mqtt->proc()){

}


$mqtt->close();

function procmsg($topic,$msg){
        echo "Msg Recieved: ".date("r")."\nTopic:{$topic}\n$msg\n";
}



?>
```